# Understanding * (zero or more) operator using re.search()

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I am new to python and was going through ["Google for Education"](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions) python course

Now, the line below confuses me:

> * -- 0 or more occurrences of the pattern to its left

(all the examples are in python3)

e.g. 1

```
In [1]: re.search(r"pi*", "piiig!!").group()
Out[1]: 'piii'
```

This is fine since, "pi" has 1 occurrance so it is retured

e.g. 2

```
In [2]: re.search(r"i*", "piiig!!").group()
Out[2]: ''
```

Why does it not return "i" in fact - from my understanding, it should be returning "iii". But the result is an empty string.

Also, What exactly does "0 or more" mean? I searched on google but everywhere it is mentioned * -- 0 or more. But if there is 0 occurrence of an expression, does that not become true even if it's not there? What is the point of searching then?

I am so confused with this. Can you please help me with explaining this or point me in the right direction.

i hope the right explanation would also resolve my this issue:

```
In [3]: re.search(r"i?", "piiig!!").group()
Out[3]: ''
```

I have tried the examples in [Spyder 3.2.4](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder)

Comment: The point of "0 or more" is mostly because you can concatenate regular expressions. So `pi*g` matches `pg` or `pig` or `piiiig` but not `peg` or `poig`.

Comment: There's a regexp tutorial at regular-expression.info. I suggest you go through it.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I think this question is in the sense of talking about the specific behavior of `re.search()` with a `*` not a duplicate. But the title has to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is a bit more complicated than the answers we have seen so far.

First, unlike `re.match()` the primitive operation [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does by default) and finds the pattern **once**:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular
>   expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding
>   MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches
>   the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length
>   match at some point in the string. See: [Ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

If we follow every step of the regex engine while it tries to find a match, we can observe the following for the pattern `i*` and the test string `piigg!!`:

[image: RegExBuddy Debug till End Output]

As you can see, the first character (at position 0) produces a match because `p` is zero times `i` and the result is an empty match (and not p - because we do not search for p or any other character).
At the second character (position 1) the second match (spanning to position 2) is found since `ii` is zero or more times `i`... at position 3 there is another empty match, and so far and so forth.

Because `re.search` only returns the first match it sticks with the first empty match at position 0. That's why you get the (confusing) result you have posted:

```
In [2]: re.search(r"i*", "piiig!!").group()
Out[2]: ''
```

In order to match every occurrence, you need `re.findall()`:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match. See: [Ref](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation. This is exactly what i was looking for. The other answers are just stating what is written in the course document as is but you answer explains the how and why.

Comment: also, https://regex101.com/ is a great place to test out and understand regex. ty

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *(0 or more) and +(1 or more) properly to get your desired output

Eg: 1 Matches because you have defined * only for "i", this patter will capture all the "p" or "pi" combination

Eg: 2 If you need to match only "i" you need to use "+" instead of "*".

If you use "*"

```
In: re.search(r"pi*g", "piiig!!").group()
```

This will return if you input is ("pig" or "piig" or "pg")

If you use "+"

```
In: re.search(r"pi+g", "piiig!!").group()
```

This will return if you input is ("pig" or "piig")

Answer (score 0):

The special charecter `*` means 0 or more occurrence of the preceding character. For eg. `a*` matches with 0 or more occurrence of a which could be `''`, `'a'`, `'aa'` etc. This happens because `''` has 0 occurrence of `a`. 
To get `iii` you should have used `+` instead of `*` and thus would have got the first non zero  sequence of `'i'` which is `iii`

```
re.search("i+", "piiig!!").group()
```

Comment: i know what "+" operator does. "*" is 0 or more so what is the significance of using it, that was my question.

Answer (score 0):

Because `''` is the first matched result of `r'i*'` and `'iii'` is the second matched result.

```py
In [1]: import re

In [2]: re.findall(r'i*', 'piiig!!')
Out[2]: ['', 'iii', '', '', '', '']
```

This website will also explain the way how regular expression work.
https://regex101.com/r/XVPXMv/1